# SQL plages de dates

Tags: mysql

I ask myself why this request

```
SELECT * FROM world.city WHERE '20181109' > datedebut  and '20181109' < datefin;
```

doesn't return the same result as this

```
SELECT * FROM world.city WHERE  datedebut < 20181109 < datefin;
```

The last select sentence is not valid SQL, but mathematically it is the optimal solution

Comment: bienvenue á Stackoverflow. s'il vous plait, pose vos questions a cette site en anglais...

Comment: do this question broke any stackoverflow rules? - if yes then give link and precise which one

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski From this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content "Please do not translate questions for the OP."

Comment: @mx0 - I edit that question and delete French text

Comment: I think the title still needs to be translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each operator (ie `<` or `>` ) there must be a distinct right and left side.

When you write `datedebut < 20181109 < datefin` it is parsed as `datedebut < 20181109` and the result of that comparison is sent to the next operator.

You need to think differently when writing SQL than when writing mathematics. You can argument that both "languages" have parsers, but they are slightly different.

**EDIT comment:**
As I have been made aware in the comments, My original answer was not entirely correct, since that would ave given a parse error. The essence is correct: *Your query is not being parsed as you expected.*

As others have answered, if you want a more compact answer, you need to use the `BETWEEN` keyword instead of the `<`and `>` operators.

Comment: This is not actually correct. MySQL parses `a < b < c` as `(a < b) < c` so it compares a and b and gets true or false, which in a numeric context is either 1 or 0. It then compares that value to c to get the result of the operation. So for example `1<2<3 = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a MySQL expression syntax which more closely matches your second form, which is [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELECT * FROM world.city WHERE '20181109' BETWEEN datedebut AND datefin
```